# Puppeteer, click only working within page.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

This fails to click the element:

```
await page.click(
  "#trigger > ytcp-dropdown-trigger > div > div.right-container.style-scope.ytcp-dropdown-trigger > tp-yt-iron-icon"
);
```

However, this succeeds, and the expected drop down menu is revealed.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let el: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(
    "#trigger > ytcp-dropdown-trigger > div > div.right-container.style-scope.ytcp-dropdown-trigger > tp-yt-iron-icon"
  );
  el.click();
});
```

I would prefer the first one to work, and since they are both using the same selector I am not sure why it is not working.

Youtube has alot of JS on this page, and I am thinking that this unexpected behavior is site-specific.  Even if I use page.evaluate to click the dropdown arrow, and then wait for another expected element to be in the DOM, and then click that element, the click of the drop down menu item is not registering.  I tried with both page.click(...) and page.evaluate(...) for the drop down menu item.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with the URL. This often has to do with visibility and element size, but it's hard to say blindly. Puppeteer's click is designed to emit a trusted event, so it actually scrolls the element into view, moves the mouse over the element and mouses down, then mouses up, which is a totally different approach than simply firing the handler as the native DOM click does, which doesn't care about visibility.

Comment: @ggorlen Hi, the URL is behind a login page, so would also need an account, and I cannot provide one.  I will say that it is the Youtube Studio Analytics page, and the drop down menu on that page which allows the user to select the timespan of the analytics to be exports (i.e. 28 days, Lifetime).  Youtube does not have a url to the CSV export I am trying to download, as they are using JS to initiate the download requests.  

I found a work around though, instead of manipulating the drop down menu, I am instead changing GET query parameters to achieve the same end result.

Comment: Good -- yes, query params are usually the best approach. I didn't realize it was behind a login. Sometimes you can get the whole page with [a utility like this](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile) and make it reproducible.